# How to tell Windows 8 to only connect to network drives on certain networks?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a home server with some files on that I connect to via my wireless LAN at home. The server is only available at that specific network, and not via internet.

It seems that every time I open an instance of explorer (as in folder viewing) Windows tries to connect to the drive (as it should). This seems to cause a few seconds lag every time I'm opening a folder or e.g. using the save-file dialogue while connected to another network.

To avoid my first world problem of folder lag likely caused by Windows beeing unable to connect to network drives, how do I set Windows only to try to connect when on certain networks?

I'm using Windows 8.1, but I guess the solution could be similar in earlier version of Windows. If there is no graphical way, I'm would still be glad for a command line version.

Comment: Basically Windows should not map those drives at all, unless you're connected to the home network. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it takes windows quite some time to realize that they are not present, locking the whole folder while thinking. It doesn't seem to happen all the time. Perhaps controlling this is not open to users at all?